# How to force Bootstrap panel-title to be in a certain width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, panel

I have a cshtml file in which I have a label with class panel-title. This label is should float to the right because there's another element to the left.
Since I don't know what resolution the page will be displayed in, I want to set the width of the label to be 97% of the div it is in.
Out of some reason, the width is set on run to 350px. It causes issues on smaller screens.

I've tried to set width in jquery but it doesn't seem to work. 
I also tried to delete the entire style - didn't work.
I know it's because of this class since when I changed the class it didn't work.
OF COURSE I've been searching my code for "350" and "350px" and nothing came up !!

Changing the class parmenantly is not an option since there are too many adaptations to make and it might cause bigger issues.

```html
     <div style="width: 30%; float: right;">
            <label id="SomeId" class="panel-default" style="width: 97%; float: right;">
                 <a id="AnotherId" >My text here</a>
            </label>
        </div>
```

When I check developers tools I see that there's an inline style:
 `"width: 350px".` I don't want it there. I want it to be either empty or 97%.

Any ideas?

Comment: share your full code in fiddle

Comment: Sounds like you got some ghost javascript adding the inline style. Have you tried disabling javascript in developer tools and see if you still get width added?

Comment: I can't disable javascript or shar my full code since it's part of a system with a lot of files and also... javascripts. But I did searched for anything like it and just couldn't find what causes it